# Print Probabilities from CoreNLP Pipeline

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm aware of the functionality of using `printProbs` from a classifier to print the probabilities that a particular token is a particular ner type. However, how can I access the CRFClassifier used by the CoreNLP pipeline in the bottom code to actually call the `printProb` method?

```
    // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);


    // run all Annotators on this text
    pipeline.annotate(document);
```

Comment: I think this a very reasonable thing to ask for and I would like to hear an answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach I would say is to have your own custom ner annotator which resembles very closely the CRFClassifier and add that to your pipeline instead of ner. So basically start with a copy of that code and then from within there you can access the CRFClassifier methods which contain the cliques and the probabilities

Answer (score 0):

One could also use reflection (hahaha)

```
NERCombinerAnnotator nerAnnotator = (NERCombinerAnnotator) StanfordCoreNLP.getExistingAnnotator(Annotator.STANFORD_NER);
Field field = nerAnnotator.getClass().getDeclaredField("ner");
field.setAccessible(true);
NERClassifierCombiner classifier = (NERClassifierCombiner) field.get(nerAnnotator);
Field field2 = ner.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("baseClassifiers");
field2.setAccessible(true);
// one of these will be the CRFClassifier used
List baseClassifiers = (List) field2.get(ner);
```

You should also realize that a number of the usual reflection exceptions could be raised using this code.